# Generate Jasper reports without text boxes

Tags: jasper-reports

When I generate an RTF report with Jasper each text field and static text that I declared in JRXML are converted in Text Boxes

[[image: RTF Jasper Report]

I need to generate an base64 then and send to an webservice which were build from other people. The problem is that this webservice did not process those text boxes which Jasper generate.

As far as I realize this is not an Jasper problem it is an problem from Webservice´s API which do not process that component however is there some configuration to generate reports in Jasper without this text boxes just text and enters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording [Jaspersoft Community](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537075/rtf-without-frames)

> Unfortunately there's no possibility to avoid RTF textboxes at the moment.Due to pixel-perfect output requirements, the RTF exporter in JR is based on textbox-layout.

So I will try anoter RTF exporter